# Visualforce page opening in new page, i want it to open in new tab? Can anyone assist

Tags: jquery, popup, window, salesforce, visualforce

How can I open new tab as opposed to a new window using visualforce
Here is my code, Please advice how/what should I change/add here

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>

    <apex:form >
        <apex:outputPanel id="myPanel">
            <h1>Status: </h1>
              {!responseMessage}
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>  

 <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() 
        {
            console.log('----'+{!redirectToLead}); 
            if({!redirectToLead})
           //sforce.one.navigateToURL("/{!leadId}"'_self');
           window.location.href = "/{!leadId}";

        }); 
</script>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `window.open("/{!leadId}", "_blank");` instead of `window.location.href = "/{!leadId}";`

But you can't control if it will open in a new tab or in a new window, that's a browser user preference.

Comment: Superb! Worked. Thanks Aabilio

Answer (score 0):

Instead of -> window.location.href = "/{!leadId}";

Can you use -> window.open("https://www.youraddress.com","_self")